# Unable to do anything because im stuck on a single screen with dual monitor setup

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors

My second monitor is not being detected on my main ubuntu account(writing this from guest atm). This leaves me with a dead screen and one screen that does not have my toolbar on it.

I can't launch the terminal with the keyboard shortcut or get the settings with right mouse click on desktop. I'm guessing they are opened on my main monitor.

Is there any way to reset the display options on my main account from another account?

I am ready to throw my pc out the window.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get into a tty using <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>. If you can, look at your settings in

```
sudo nano ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

If you can't <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> from your main account, try booting into recovery mode and opening a shell from there. Then `cd` into your user profile from root.